# Changing drawable in ImageView crashes android app

Tags: android, memory-management

So I'm writing a piece of software and it keeps crashing when I try to create a second drawable. It starts out on the front screen, then I push a button and it goes to a new activity. On that activity I have an ImageView in the middle and a button on the bottom. When the activity loads there is a drawable in the ImageView. So when I click on the button at the bottom it is supposed to change the drawable that is in the ImageView but it crashes. I found errors in the LogCat that say things like:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1385): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

So here is my code from that activity:

```
package com.foocity.android.gui;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class NewMapActivity extends Activity 
{
    public ImageView    mapPreview;
    public Drawable     currentPic;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newmap);

        currentPic = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.milestone_cleanenergy);
        mapPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chooseCanvas);
        mapPreview.setImageDrawable(currentPic);
    }

    public void changePic(View view)
    {
        System.out.println("tester boy!!!!!!!!!!!");

        currentPic = null;
        currentPic = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.welcomescreen);
        mapPreview.setImageDrawable(currentPic);
    }
}
```

And here is what the LogCat says when it crashes:

```
06-13 21:25:56.613: D/dalvikvm(4086): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 614 objects / 50072 bytes in 58ms
06-13 21:26:02.133: W/System.err(4086): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/000.txt (No such file or directory)
06-13 21:26:02.143: W/System.err(4086):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
06-13 21:26:02.143: W/System.err(4086):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
06-13 21:26:02.143: W/System.err(4086):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:82)
06-13 21:26:02.143: W/System.err(4086):     at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:188)
06-13 21:26:02.143: W/System.err(4086):     at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:167)
06-13 21:26:02.143: W/System.err(4086):     at com.foocity.android.Map.<init>(Map.java:33)
06-13 21:26:02.143: W/System.err(4086):     at com.foocity.android.FooCity.setMap(FooCity.java:594)
06-13 21:26:02.143: W/System.err(4086):     at com.foocity.android.gui.StartActivity.chooseMap(StartActivity.java:33)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-13 21:26:02.153: W/System.err(4086):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 21:26:02.393: D/dalvikvm(4086): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3101 objects / 159528 bytes in 53ms
06-13 21:26:07.113: I/System.out(4086): tester boy!!!!!!!!!!!
06-13 21:26:07.123: E/dalvikvm-heap(4086): 9469350-byte external allocation too large for this process.
06-13 21:26:07.123: E/GraphicsJNI(4086): VM won't let us allocate 9469350 bytes
06-13 21:26:07.133: D/AndroidRuntime(4086): Shutting down VM
06-13 21:26:07.133: W/dalvikvm(4086): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at com.foocity.android.gui.NewMapActivity.changePic(NewMapActivity.java:30)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     ... 11 more
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
06-13 21:26:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(4086):     ... 15 more
```

It obviously has something to do with memory management, which I'm not use to monitoring with Java, but I'm not really sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

P.S. I realized as posting this that I tried something else (creating a file object and then writing it's content to System.out) and it caused the same error even before the new activity loaded the first drawable in the ImageView so it must have everything to do with memory management, I guess I need help with how to manage memory in this system because I am used to the GC taking care of that in regular Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

From this line it is evident that image you are trying to display is excessive size. Try to reduce the size of the image and see.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is that you're trying to draw one image over another, and your app is running out of memory as a result. I'm not sure how, but try clearing the ImageView before you draw the next image.

EDIT: [Displaying Bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)
That should help you solve your problem.

Comment: I don't think that is it, as I said at the end when I create a File object and write it to the System.out the program will crash before it gets to the ImageView even. Also when I run: currentPic = null; and then currentPic = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blah); and use a debug session it gives me the error about the memory allocation before even running the mapPreview.setImageDrawable(currentPic); so it has to do with memory management but not that specific idea of putting another pic on the ImageView on top of another.

Comment: If thats the case then the image is apparently too large. And as far as I know, theres no way to increase the amount of memory allocated to your application.

Answer (score 0):

> 06-13 21:26:07.123: E/dalvikvm-heap(4086): 9469350-byte external allocation too large for this process.
>   06-13 21:26:07.123: E/GraphicsJNI(4086): VM won't let us allocate 9469350 bytes

This tells that image resource you use as the `R.drawable.welcomescreen` is too big (its bitmap takes ~9 MBytes). I strongly believe you could downscale the image resource (before putting it to "drawable" folder), so it does not take so much memory.

Comment: So, that isn't actually the issue. The pictures were actually only about 350kB with their sizes added together, but I did solve it. So The first activity (Where I push the button to go in the second one) had a pic on it too, but I set it differently. The one on the first activity I set in the xml with android:src="@drawable/blah.jpg" instead of in a method like I did the second time. When I removed that line from the xml and set the pic on the first activity in a method like I did in the second activities ImageView, everything worked fine. My question now is why did that work?

Answer (score 0):

The ImageView on the first activity I set in the xml with android:src="@drawable/blah.jpg" instead of in a method like I did the second time. When I removed that line from the xml and set the pic on the first activity in a method like I did in the second activities ImageView, everything worked fine. The question now is why did this work? Why does setting a pic in the xml take up so much more memory space?

Comment: So I'm really confused now, I was playing with it and doing it both ways is working now. I thought that is what I changed but who knows what the problem is. But in the end it is working fine now. Will just have to wait and see what happens in the future.